# ASP.NET MVC5 Why doesn't post action Delete get called?

Tags: asp.net, post, asp.net-mvc-5

In my controller, ProductsController, I have this post action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        MyModel db = new MyModel();
        CATEGORY category = db.CATEGORY.Find(id);
        db.CATEGORY.Remove(category);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ProductDetails");
    }
```

In my view, DeleteCategory.cshtml, I am trying to call delete like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ProductsList")
        </div>
    }
```

However, nothing happens when I click the button Delete.
I've tried putting the controller and the action name in Html.BeginForm but it didn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The form is being posted? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must give controller and action names to BeginForm

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete","Your controller name without ControllerSuffix"),FormMethod.POST)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I didn't know I have to remove the ControllerSuffix